# SwiftUI ViewModel keeps init forever

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewmodel

I have the structure like this.

```
import SwiftUI

//create a simple view model
class ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = "World"
    //create a reference of another viewmodel
    let anotherViewModel = AnotherViewModel()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("init")
        Settings.shared.test = "2"
    }
}

//create another view model
class AnotherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = "World"
    init(){
        print("another init")
        Settings.shared.test = "3"
    }
}

//create singleton with a bool
class Settings: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Settings()
    @Published var isShow: Bool = false
    @Published var test = "1"
}

struct FatherView: View {
    @StateObject var settings = Settings.shared//if I remove this line, it will be normal.
    var body:some View{
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    //@StateObject var settingsHolder = Settings.shared
    @StateObject var model: ViewModel
    @StateObject var model1: AnotherViewModel
    init() {
        let model = ViewModel()
        _model = StateObject(wrappedValue: model)
        _model1 = StateObject(wrappedValue: model.anotherViewModel)
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hi")
        }
    }
}
```

Once I change the value of settings parameters, the two view model will repeat init forever, and it seems only happen when I put the `ContentView` into `FatherView` and declare the @StateObject of settings in the

Comment: `@StateObject` isn't for view models try creating custom `View` structs, it's designed to hold the view data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct, because when you're initializing both `ViewModel` and `AnotherViewModel`, you also set the `Settings.shared` value, which was stored in `ContentView`. It's the cause of looping.

```
FatherView -> get ContentView -> init ViewModel -> Setting.shared.test -> get Content -> Setting.shared.test -> Loop...
```

Try to remove `Settings.shared.test` inside two init functions.

Btw, you might consider taking a look at [.environmentObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject), an alternative way to pass dependency instead of a singleton.